# Differential equation $x'=t^2 \tan x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x'=t^2 \tan x$

I tried to do it like a equation with separated variables but the integral was too difficult so probably I have to do it in the other way but I have no idea how right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\cot x\,dx=t^2\,dt\implies \int \cot x\,dx=\int t^2\,dt\implies \ln|\sin x|={t^3\over 3}+C$$

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself. ;-) Glad to help.